# JS parsing array of objects with external data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

This might sound really trivial but I don't know how what I'm trying to achieve is called and what's the best approach here. Any hints would be really helpful.

I have some variables:

```
const foo = true;
const bar = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

And then a set of items:

```
const itemList = [
    {
    login: 'name',
    password: bar.a,
    isActive: foo ? true : false,
  },
  {
    login: 'name2',
    password: bar.c,
    isActive: foo ? true : false,
  }
];
```

I need to apply the variable values to `itemList` so I should end up with is:

```
const result = [
  {
    login: 'name',
    password: 'a',
    isActive: true,
  },
  {
    login: 'name2',
    password: 'c',
    isActive: true,
  },
  {
    login: 'name3',
    password: 'b',
    isActive: true,
  }
]
```

Would `map` be the most performant option here? Note my itemList and variables are quite long.

I've tried this approach, but it seems to be returning only `[true, true, true]`:

```
const result = itemList.map((item) => (
    item.login = item.login,
    item.password = bar[bar.indexOf(item.password)],
    item.isActive = foo
));
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that array `bar` does not have any properties names `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'`. Those are values that correspond to indices `0`, `1`, and `2`, respectively. In other words: `bar.a`, `bar.b`, and `bar.c` will produce the value `undefined`. Note also that your "list of items" has logic embedded within it (use of the ternary conditional operator): perhaps you intended that logic to be positioned elsewhere, in a function?

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with some constructs, it's probably best to check the documentation. That is not how `Array.prototype.map()` works. Currently you are returning an expression with two comma operators, effectively returning `item.isActive = foo` (which in turn results in `foo`) for every element in the array. It is also not clear to me what `bar.a` means, given that `bar` is an array and not an object. In your example you are basically returning the value itself if it exists in the array and otherwise you return `undefined`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Wordpressor ... From all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few observations/suggestion **:**

- `bar` is an array of primitive values. Hence, There is no properties names 'a', 'b', or 'c' available. You can access the values via `index`.
- As foo contains `boolean` value. Hence, Instead of `foo ? true : false` we can directly use `foo`.
- I am little confused with the password value. It is dynamic and fill as per the index from bar array or it is hard coded as `name2` having password `C` ?

```js
const foo = true;
const bar = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const itemList = [
    {
    login: 'name',
    password: null,
    isActive: null,
  },
  {
    login: 'name2',
    password: null,
    isActive: null,
  }
];

const res = itemList.map(item => {
    item.password = item.login === 'name' ? bar[0] : bar[2],
    item.isActive = foo
    return item;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have some variables:
>
> ```
> const foo = true;
> const bar = ["a", "b", "c"];
>
> const itemList = [{
>   login: 'name',
>   password: bar.a,
>   isActive: foo ? true : false,
> }, {
>   login: 'name2',
>   password: bar.c,
>   isActive: foo ? true : false,
> }];
> ```

In case of the above written code, the assignments of `password: b.a` and `password: b.c` both result in assigning the `undefined` value, due to `bar` being an array which does not feature any additional own properties like `a`, `b`, `c` etc. ...,

The code would work though in case it provides an index/map based lookup approach like this ...

```js
const foo = true;
const bar = ["a", "b", "c"]
  // create an index/map/lookup
  // from the above provided array.
  .reduce((index, value) => {
    index[value] = value;
    return index;
  }, {});

const itemList = [{
  login: 'name',
  password: bar.a,
  isActive: !!foo,
  // the line above delivers the same result
  // but is much shorter than the original term.
  // // isActive: foo ? true : false,
}, {
  login: 'name2',
  password: bar.c,
  isActive: !!foo,
}];

console.log({ bar, itemList });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... or altered even more to that ...

```js
const foo = true;
const bar = ["a", "b", "c"];

const barValueLookup = new Map(
  // create a real `Map` instance by passing
  // the accordingly mapped bar array.
  bar.map(value => [value, value])
);
const itemList = [{
  login: 'name',
  password: barValueLookup.get('a'),
  isActive: !!foo,
}, {
  login: 'name2',
  password: barValueLookup.get('c'),
  isActive: !!foo,
}];

console.log({ lookupEntries: [...barValueLookup], itemList });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In case the OP can not touch the code which declares and assigns the entire `const` setup, the OP needs to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over `itemList` in order to achieve the desired `result` array. But then following precondition always needs to be met ... `bar` items have to be aligned each by its index according to its related `itemList` item.

```js
const foo = true;
const bar = ["a", "b", "c"];

const itemList = [{
  login: 'name',
  password: bar.a,
  isActive: foo ? true : false,
}, {
  login: 'name1',
  password: bar.b,
  isActive: foo ? true : false,
}, {
  login: 'name2',
  password: bar.c,
  isActive: foo ? true : false,
}];

// above code can not be touched/changed

// ... BUT ... `bar` items are aligned
// each by its index according to its
// related `itemList` item.

const result = itemList
  .map(({ password, ...itemRest }, idx) => ({
    ...itemRest,
    password: bar[idx],
  }));

console.log({ bar, itemList, result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const foo = true;
const bar = ["a", "b", "c"];
const itemList = [
    {
    login: 'name',
    password: '',
    isActive: foo ? true : false,
  },
  {
    login: 'name2',
    password: '',
    isActive: foo ? true : false,
  }
];
const result = itemList.map((item,index) => ({
    login: item.login,
    password: bar[index],
    isActive: foo}
));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: In OP's example, the object with `login` `name2`, has the `password` property set to `"c"`, not `"b"`.